# Setting wordpress site to root folder on WAMP local install

Tags: wordpress, apache, wamp, vhosts, multisite

So I'm trying to set up a local test environment for a WordPress site I am planning to make. I currently have a few sites I plan to work on as a subfolder under /WWW/ but I'm trying to use a addon for multisites https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/#installation , My problems however is that I'm new and I installed the addon, but the addon wants my site to be in root. However root for wamp has a bunch of files used for wamp at the moment and I also have multiple subfolders in root for other sites i'm planning on having in that test environment.

I'm trying to figure out how to make wamp think my one site is the root folder, my attempts with the vhost files have failed me so far. My other option is to try and do the work of the plug in manually some how with the vhost files. Any help is appreciated

Comment: What you need to is set up a local subdomain. There are plenty of tutorials online, just Google "Local Subdomain Wamp"

Comment: @WizardCoder How about for multisites? like if I wanted site1.site.com or something. My original attempt was to use that plugin I mentioned for a network of sites, but it wanted things to be in root which got weird in wamp.

Comment: [See this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665064/project-links-do-not-work-on-wamp-server/23990618#23990618) Make a Virtual Host for each of your projects, ___specially if you are using WordPress___